# How do you write what you piped to grep into a file if only the grep matches

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, grep

Lets say i run the following command

```
 echo "I love the west indies " | grep indies
```

since the grep above evalautes to true since there will be an actual match i want to write " i love the west  indies" to file

say i run

```
echo "i love the west  indies " | grep america
```

nothing get written since this grep command returns nothing. How do i do this in bash ?

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the output with [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and test the result before writing to file:

```
result=$(echo "I love the west indies" | grep indies)
if [ -n "$result" ]
then echo "$result" > output.file
fi
```

The quotes around `"$result"` in the 'echo to output' line are crucial.

You might also note that if you write nothing to a file, all that's created is an empty file.  And appending nothing to a pre-existing file only changes the timestamp on it.  So you might be able to use one of these:

```
echo "I love the west indies" | grep indies > output.file   # Zaps previous content
echo "I love the west indies" | grep indies >> output.file  # Keeps previous content
```

optionally followed by:

```
[ -s output.file ] || rm -f output.file
```

which removes the output file if it is empty.  You'd want to use a variable for the file name in place of `output.file` if you mention the name more than once in the script.

Comment: Note that you can also write `if result=$(echo "..." | grep ...); then` and the value returned by grep will be evaluated by the `if`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks — yes, you could.  I tend not to use assignments like that in `if` conditions (I don't remember if I once had a good reason not to, but it's likely to a 30-year old reason if I did), but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do conditional redirection:

```
echo "I love the west indies " | awk '/indies/ { print $0 > "my_file" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash's regex:

```
$ [[ $(echo "I love the west indies ") =~ .*indies.* ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} > file
```

and when you `cat file`:

```
I love the west indies
```